# is it possible to use html tags in gml file?

Tags: gml

is there any way to use html anchor tag in a gml file..I want to create a hyperlink to location/point in a gml file.
how can i do so???
thanks in advance..

Comment: If it's possible then it could be abused or misused. So I think it's not possible. Or even desired...

Comment: den how could i use xlink attribute in my gml file??? i hav tried a lot but its not working..

Answer (score 1):

This is a little known GML technique that GREATLY increases the power of Game Maker, and is well worth learning, but as a note, it does NOT work in Studio, because of the countless new restrictions on commands. Go back to GM8.1 (I only ever use that now), and you should have no problem making use of this technique.

The technique is to write a program in another language through GML (batch, vbs, etc, or in this case, HTLM), execute it through GML, then delete the program.

Quite simply, use the file_text commands to create a file with the correct content and extension, execute it with execute_program, and then delete it with file_delete.

Specifically for this script:

- argument0 is the link, including the protocol.
- argument1 is the anchor, minus the # (that's handled for you).
- argument2 is the full browser path.
- argument3 is important. This is the time in milliseconds the program will wait before deleting the temporary link file.

(The execute_program command, even when told to wait for the program to complete, continues as soon as the temp file is loaded. If external, the redirect takes some time depending on your connection, so deleting the temporary file halfway through will cause it to fail. 10 milliseconds worked fine for me. The program will hang for this time in this setup, but if you would like to set up an alarm based system to stop it from hanging, that wouldn't be too hard.)

In other uses of this technique without the use of the internet (I use small batch and vbs files a lot), the "hang time" (pun not intended) is usually not necessary.

In addition, the browser location will need to be changed for each different computer

```
file=file_text_open_write(temp_directory+"\tempLink.html")
file_text_write_string(file,'<!DOCTYPE html>')
file_text_writeln(file)
file_text_write_string(file,'<html>')
file_text_writeln(file)
file_text_write_string(file,'<body onload="')
file_text_write_string(file,"location.href='")
file_text_write_string(file,argument0+"#"+argument1+"';")
file_text_write_string(file,'">')
file_text_writeln(file)
file_text_write_string(file,'</body>')
file_text_writeln(file)
file_text_write_string(file,'</html>')

file_text_close(file)

execute_program(argument2,temp_directory+"\tempLink.html",true)

sleep(argument3)

file_delete(temp_directory+"\tempLink.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry** I wish It was possible but it's not unless you want to spend a lot of time with dll's. BUT you can create a Script and reuse it everywhere in your code...

script0(argument0,argument1...)